# Oracle Sequences - Can we rollback a sequence

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sequence

I am using oracle 11g . i came across creating sequences, it raised a question

**Is it possible to rollback a sequence using java?**

If we can , pls suggest me ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: please see to my comment for @Guntram answer

Comment: Unless you can identify an actual problem, don't try to find a solution.

Comment: @sankrish `Sequence` is designed to _always_ generate the next possible value. It can only be restarted from the beginning. There is no way to `rollback` the generated sequence, as a parallel session in another process could have already incremented it. Sequences are stateless. They get generated and never know it was useful or not. So for your situation, you may have to write your own logic. But it is near impossible to make it _thread-safe_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `alter sequence`. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2011.htm.

But note there is no real use for this. Unless you delete all records from your tables that use your sequence, you'll get errors when you use the sequence for creating unique IDs.

And you will *always* have "holes" in your generated numbers, there is no point in trying to make IDs created by sequences contiguous. Imagine user A doing an insert, user B doing another insert, user B commits, user A rolls back. The sequence number that A used will be lost, as B used a higher one.

Comment: In my case i have 5 insert statements using the same sequence . i wannted to rollback the sequence even if one of them ends in error

Comment: And what happens if another user executes the same code, creates another 5 sequence numbers, and *then* the first ends in error? Don't try to make contiguous IDs. It just won't work. You need unique IDs, which sequences guarantee, but there's no point in trying to make sure every single ID is used.

Comment: @sankrish The question still stands - *why* do you need to rollback the sequence in this case? Sequences are great for generating unique identifiers, they are not so great for generating consecutive numbers without "holes" in them.

Comment: i just wanted to reuse the sequences that are generated for partial execution .. (i.e) if 3 tables gets inserted with the value and 2 fails

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: I agree with the part of your answer that messing with the sequence is pointless at best and dangerous at worst. But I don't believe you are correct regarding alter sequence. Alter sequence does not affect starting number. Here's a sample Oracle link in that regard: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm

Comment: @Olaf, Guntram is correct - you *can* use ALTER SEQUENCE to change the INCREMENT BY - with a combination of two ALTERs and a select you can reset the start of a sequence to any value you want.

Comment: I admit i hadn't checked the syntax, but i remembered having seen it done somewhere. But you're right Jeffrey, it was done the way you explained. Thank you for clearing this up.